# Angular 2 Confitional Router Outlet Display

Tags: angular

Hi I have a situation where I want to wait for a couple of ajax calls to be executed  before I allow the angular router to display the page. I am using angular RC.

In order to achieve this I tryed to do something like this:

```
<div *ngIf="isDataLoaded">
  <header-menu"></header-menu>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <footer-app></footer>
</div>
```

The isDataLoaded variable gets changed from false to true as soon as the calls get completed in the root component of the application.

When I run the application I get the following error:

[image]

From what I read online this happens because angular does not find the router outlet imediatly on the page when it searches for it.

How can I tell angular to wait for the ajax calls to finish and then execute the components in the rotuer outlet ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `resolve` property of the route configuration.

```
export const MyRoutes: Route[] = [
  {
    path: 'my/path',
    component: MyComponent,
    resolve: {
      myData: MyResolver
    }
  }
];
```

and define a resolver class as this for instance

```
@Injectable()
export class MyResolver implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor(public http: Http) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    // const name: string = route.params['name'];
    return this.http.get('api/whatever').map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

`data` will then be available in `MyComponent` via `ActivatedRoute` instance

```
@Component({ ... })
export class MyComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
  data: any[] = [];
  routeDataSub: Subscription;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.routeDataSub = this.route.data.subscribe(data => this.data = data['myData']);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.routeDataSub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```